# How do I reference a JSON database path that contains a number, in react state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a realtime firebase database and I am trying to reference specific data that contains a number as the object name in React.

My JSON data in the database is setup like this:

```
{
  "data": {
  "423789" : {
    "acquireRewardSiteHash" : 0,
    "acquireUnlockHash" : 0,
    "action" : {
      "actionTypeLabel" : "shard",
      "consumeEntireStack" : false,
      "deleteOnAction" : true,
      "isPositive" : false,
      "requiredCooldownHash" : 0,
      "requiredCooldownSeconds" : 0,
      "rewardItemHash" : 0,
      "rewardSheetHash" : 0,
      "rewardSiteHash" : 0,
      "useOnAcquire" : false,
      "verbDescription" : "",
      "verbName" : "Dismantle"
    },
    "allowActions" : true,
    "backgroundColor" : {
      "alpha" : 0,
      "blue" : 0,
      "colorHash" : 0,
      "green" : 0,
      "red" : 0
    },
    "blacklisted" : false,
    "classType" : 1,
    "collectibleHash" : 4220193450,
    "defaultDamageType" : 0,
    "displayProperties" : {
      "description" : "PARADISE LOST: A group of castaways seek to overthrow the divine order.",
      "hasIcon" : true,
      "icon" : "/common/destiny2_content/icons/47849b754551cc0f4f03acd7554882eb.jpg",
      "name" : "Mythos Hack 4.1"
    }
}
}
}
```

I am trying to access it via a database reference like so:

```
const db = firebase.database().ref().child('data');

        this.setState({loading: true});

        db.on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({
                data: snapshot.val(),
                loading: false
            });
        });
```

I want to access the `displayProperties` object but I'm having difficulty accessing it.

I have tried to reference the object like so:

```
{this.state.data.423789.displayProperties.name}
```

But I receive a parsing error as it isn't taking the number as a name.

I have also tried wrapping the number in [], and tried referencing it like so `{this.state.data[423789].displayProperties.name}` but I am having no luck.

Is anyone able to provide me with any information on where I'm going wrong and how to reference a number in React when trying to access a JSON object?

My full code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import * as firebase from "firebase";

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            data: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const db = firebase.database().ref().child('data');

        this.setState({loading: true});

        db.on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({
                data: snapshot.val(),
                loading: false
            });
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.firebase.database().off();
    }

    render() {
        const { loading } = this.state;
        const baseURL = 'www.bungie.net';

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Home</h1>

                {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}

                <p>{this.state.data.423789.displayProperties.name}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withFirebase(Home);
```

EDIT: I have been able to access the `displayProperties` object by changing the database reference to match the object name, like this:

```
const db = firebase.database().ref().child('423789');
```

but I have more than one object of data in the database so can only access the specific object that I have referenced.

Answer (score 1):

This should work 
`{this.state.data["423789"].displayProperties.name}`

JSON can only have string value as keys. Even if you use numbers as keys they get converted to strings

Comment: This gives me a ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayProperties' of undefined```. I am able to achieve the result I want by adding ```const db = firebase.database().ref().child('data/423789/displayProperties');``` and then calling ```{this.state.data.name}``` in the render, but whenever I try to call ```{this.state.displayProperties.name``` when the ```const db``` hasn't been appended I always get an undefined error

Comment: That's because you are only setting data to your state, you are no where setting  displayProperties to state because of which you see that error(Actually you are trying to access something that's not there).